# Localizar o id dentro do array[] em json

Tags: javascript, json

Boa noite!

Estou tendo um problema ao localizar array por caso do colchetes.

Estou tentando pegar os dados de **"stats"**. Mas a unica referencia que possui é **"accountId"** ou **"summonerName"**. Para pegar a referencia do **"stats"** precisa pegar o id **"participantId"** que está dentro do **"participantIdentities"**.

Mas o meu problema é que não estou conseguindo pegar o id **"participantId"**.

Base de JSON - Exemplo

```
{  
   "gameId":1189987226,
   "participantIdentities":[  
      {  
         "player":{  
            "summonerName":"Khal Droggo",
            "accountId":1595535
         },
         "participantId":1
      },
      {  
         "player":{  
            "summonerName":"Lefetos",
            "accountId":211703728
         },
         "participantId":2
      }
   ],
   "participants":[  
      {  
         "stats":{  
            "champLevel":16,
            "participantId":1
         },
         "participantId":1
      },
      {  
         "stats":{  
            "champLevel":15,
            "participantId":2
         },
         "participantId":2
      }
   ]
}
```

Estou usando linguagem javascript.

```js
function callback(andress, fn){
    $.ajax({
        url: andress,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){},
        success: fn
    });
}

function stats(accountId){
    callback('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ew27p', function(retorno) {
        var obj = retorno.participantIdentities;
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(prop) {
            if (obj[prop].accountId == accountId) {
                document.write(obj[prop].participantId);
            }
        });
    });
}

stats(211703728);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lógica que está a utilizar para ir buscar achar o jogador funciona, só o acesso ao campo `accountId` é que não está correto, este `obj[prop].accountId`.

Se faz um `foreach` em `participantIdentities` significa que cada objeto desse `foreach` será algo como:

```
{  
     "player":{  
        "summonerName":"Khal Droggo",
        "accountId":1595535
     },
     "participantId":1
}
```

O que significa que para aceder ao `accountId` terá de fazer `.player.accountId` em vez de `.accountId` diretamente como tem.

Sendo assim basta trocar o `if` que tem para:

```
if (obj[prop].player.accountId == accountId) { //agora .player.accountId
```

Se `player` pode não existir então convem confirmar se existe utilizando a função [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) o que ficaria assim:

```
if (obj[prop].hasOwnProperty("player") && obj[prop].player.accountId == accountId) {
```

Exemplo:

```js
function callback(andress, fn){
    $.ajax({
        url: andress,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){},
        success: fn
    });
}

function stats(accountId){
    callback('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ew27p', function(retorno) {
        var obj = retorno.participantIdentities;
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(prop) {
            if (obj[prop].hasOwnProperty("player") && obj[prop].player.accountId == accountId) { //if alterado aqui
                console.log(`Achou jogador ${obj[prop].player.summonerName} com participantId de ${obj[prop].participantId}`);
                return;//se achou não ve mais nenhum
            }
        });
    });
}

stats(211703728);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A sua solução também é ótimo. Mas existe um problema, na base de JSON pode não existe array  **"accountId"**. Ou seja isso vai ocorrer um erro como `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'accountId' of undefined`.

Comment: @AugustoJunior qual array ? o `participantIdentities` ? Coloque na resposta um exemplo do json devolvido quando não existe o array que está a indicar, para que eu lhe possa indicar uma solução. Porque pelo erro que está a mostrar parece é que cada objeto do `participantIdentities` pode não ter o campo `player` definido.

Comment: Vou explicar como funciona a base de json, dentro do `participantIdentities` pode existir varias `player` e pode simplesmente não existir `player`. Ou seja se não existir `player` vai da erro neste comando `if (obj[prop].player.accountId == accountId)` porque não existe `accountId`. Quando a base de json não existe `accountId` estaria dessa maneira. https://jsfiddle.net/thLqyn4g/1/

Comment: @AugustoJunior Ver se existe é facil basta usar [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). Mas e se existir vários fica como ? fica um array de players ? Dê um exemplo em json de quando há vários. Já atualizei a resposta para o `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: Coloquei dois exemplos como json pode funcionar. Varias `player` https://jsfiddle.net/zvadty2t/ e sem `player` https://jsfiddle.net/d55ymadL/

Comment: @AugustoJunior de acordo com esses exemplos a minha edição já irá funcionar. Peço assim que confirme se há algum caso que não esteja a funcionar

Comment: Muitoooo obrigado! Com essa função `hasOwnProperty` funcionou perfeito!

Answer (score 0):

Com base na resposta de uma pergunta feita no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23721038/8353154)

A melhor solução é usar o método `grep` do [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/).

```
var participante = $.grep( obj, function( n, i ) {
    return n.player.accountId===accountId;
});
```

Para recuperar o valor de `participantId`

```
participante[0].participantId
```

Ficando assim seu código.

```js
function callback(andress, fn){
    $.ajax({
        url: andress,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){},
        success: fn
    });
}

function stats(accountId){
    callback('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ew27p', function(retorno) {
      var obj = retorno.participantIdentities;
      var participante = $.grep( obj, function( n, i ) {
        return n.player.accountId===accountId;
      });
      console.log(participante[0].participantId);
    });
}

stats(211703728);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Em vez de usar **forEach** devo usar **grep**. Cara muito obrigado, resolveu o meu problema!.

Comment: Uma pergunta bem simples, como recuperar o valor dentro do **"player"** `participante[0].summonerName`?

Comment: `participante[0].player.summonerName`

Comment: Uma duvidá caso não existir accountId na base JSON, isso vai ocorrer um erro, como tratar isso?